# PHP JSON error parsing the JSON document. The document may not be well-formed

Tags: php, json

This is my code:

```
 if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") {
 include_once('../database/dbSource.php');

 $databaseSource = DataBaseSource::getInstance();

  //Parse
  $ini_array = parse_ini_file("../../pto/config.ini");

  $user = $_GET['userSid'];
$username = $ini_array['ctsi_CIBMON_fid'];
$password = $ini_array['ctsi_CIBMON_pass'];
$ctsi_url = $ini_array['ctsi_url'] . $user . '&view=full';

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" . "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
            "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
echo file_get_contents($ctsi_url, false, $context);
} else {
echo $_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"];
}
```

I get the following error :

> There was an error parsing the JSON document. The document may not be
>   well-formed.

I tried checking addiitonal spaces in code (which i removed) etc.

Also there is no issues with authorization.

Can't figure out what's the issue.

Please help.

Note: Also it used to work but stopped working without any change to code even. so Strange.

also the url that i am trying to access is https://xxx.xxx.net not http - does it matter?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the remote file directly in your browser? Do you get a valid JSON response?

Comment: Yes ! when i access the url with username and password it does return data - although it's in xml format

Comment: Well that's probably the problem then.  Your code is expecting a JSON response.  It seems like the provider of the remote file changed the format.

Comment: yes it allows JSON as well (which used to work) and also i have header('Content-Type: application/json');
 at the top.

Comment: Another thing to note is : it still works fine in my local machine with the same code - just not on DEV,TEST environments. any idea why ?